# PHP - SOAP with SSL : "Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from..."

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm losing my mind here.

I used the same webservice with soap with login/password, it always worked fine. But now my client wants to use ssl.
He gave me a new url and everything, but I can't find a way to make it work.

I obtain `Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'service.jsp?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "service.jsp?wsdl`.

Oh, and with curl it works, so there is definitively a problem with my parameters.

Here is my code (found on a forum) :

```
$soap = new SoapClient("service.jsp?wsdl"
    ,array("stream_context"=>stream_context_create(
              array(
                 "location"=>"https://xxxxxxx/services/",
                "ssl"=>array(
                    "verify_peer"=>true
                    ,"allow_self_signed"=>false
                    ,"cafile"=>$certif
                    ,"verify_depth"=>5
                    ,"CN_match"=>"https://xxxxxxx/services/"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

I've tried so much different things that I don't know what's important or not…

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, after hours and days of research.
If someone has the same problem :

All I had to do was to create a .pem file containing the key and the certificate and write :

```
$soap = new SoapClient("service.jsp?wsdl",array('local_cert'=>$key_cert_file));
```

So easy… right ?